# How to supress page numbers when rendering a R script into a pdf document using rmarkdown::render()

Tags: r, r-markdown

In my team, we are taking advantage of the potential of *RMarkdown* to generate the documentation of different R scripts from the script's comments ([see tutorial here](https://happygitwithr.com/r-test-drive.html)). While everything is working nicely, we are having troubles suppressing page numbers from the pdf documents we generate.

None of the solutions found around the web for R markdown documents seem to work with this particular method. They either throw and error (e.g. `Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line xx, column yy`) or do not change the output whatsoever.

We are looking for either a way to supress page numbers that actually works with this particular method to generate documentation, or a way to keep the *.tex* file so we can make the modifications ourselves. All approaches are welcome and much appreciated (and we apologize in advance if we actually missed a solution in ancient community posts).

Below I provided you with a reproducible example (please be aware of the information regarding the last step to avoid errors):

```
#' ---
#' title: "Dummy procedure to test R script rendering with Rmarkdown"
#' author: "Jean Doe"
#' date: "June 6, 2225"
#' output: pdf_document
#' ---
#'
#'
#' This is a dummy procedure to test the possibility of documenting scripts from comments.  
#' In order to do so, I'm going to provide a few R commands, then render it with `rmarkdown::render` function. Let's begin:
#'
#'
#'First I create my variables:
#+ setvar_chunk, eval = FALSE 
#variables
x <- seq(1,10,2)
y <- x^2

#'Then I have a data.frame
#+ df_chunk, eval = FALSE 
#data.frame
df <- data.frame(x,y)

#'Then I plot it but the plot is not going to appear in the *rmarkdown document* because i'm interesting in documenting my code not in creating a report. However, when I run my code, it actually does the job and plots y against x 
#+ plot_chunk, eval = FALSE 
#Plotting
plot (df)

#' My last step is to generate the documentation so when I change something I know that by just being descriptive and thorough in my comments I can actually generate my documentation at the same time I run my script. I can also "comment" this last part so i'm not constantly generating documentation when the script is meant to be run again and again.  
#' 
#' 
#' To avoid *errors* you need to save the script in your HDD, then substitute "FileToPath/File.R" with your path and file name
#+ eval = FALSE  
rmarkdown::render(input = "FileToPath/File.R", 
                  output_format = c("pdf_document"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `\pagenumbering{gobble}` directly in your preamble in the following way (indicating the underlying/transitional *.tex* file that numbers should not be printed):

```
---
#' title: "Dummy procedure to test R script rendering with Rmarkdown"
#' author: "Jean Doe"
#' date: "June 6, 2225"
#' output: pdf_document
#' header-includes:
#'    - \pagenumbering{gobble}
---
```